# Populating a separate column with matching values, starting on a specific row

Tags: google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRL0E.png)How can I retrieve matches for a specific value in one column and then populate a separate column with the corresponding value from another column, starting on a specific row and incrementing downward for each match found, in Google Sheets?

This is the formula that I have generated but again it does not adequately solve what I'm looking for it to do:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A15:A,MATCH(1,(D15:D="FABIANO")*(ROW(D15:D)-ROW(D15)+1),0),COLUMN()-6),”")
```

What I want is each match for Fabiano to retrieve the associated value in column A and begin populating in column G starting at G15 onwards. Right now it is finding the correct matches but populating the values into column G of the corresponding row of each match.

Comment: added an image now

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
=MAP(A15:A,D15:D,LAMBDA(acol,dcol,
IF(dcol<>"FABIANO","",
SUMIF(D15:dcol,"FABIANO",A15:acol))))
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. I want the Fabiano matched values from column A to stack list in column G instead of appearing in the row which it was matched from. This is the issue I'm having.

Comment: Then you can use `=SCAN(,FILTER(A15:A,D15:D="FABIANO"),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v))`

Comment: This is useful since I understand you need a cumulative sum, am I right?

Comment: the answer by @player0 solved the problem. Thank you for your help also!

Comment: Great you could do it! I understood you need it cumulative because of your expression `incrementing downward` - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use this formula in G1:

```
=FILTER(A:A; D:D="fabiano")
```